# Installing own App on Rooted WebOS LG TV

Tags: drm, webos, lg

I am trying to install my own web App to a ROOTED LG TV, ignoring Developer mode status. I have successfully run it with Devmode = On, but it expires after 48 hours, and I have to do it over. I want to use the TV as a menu display. I can install my App, using `"ApplicationInstallerUtility -c install -p /tmp/com.xxx.xxx_1.0.0_all.ipk -u 0 -l /media/cryptofs -d"`, but when I try to start it with Developer Mode = Off , using ssh and `luna://com.webos.applicationManager/launch`, I get an error code 302, and a text "errorText": "Failed to identify a proper DRM file". 
What can I do to solve this issue? How can I sign my app, without going to LG content store? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Many DRM implementations will have a check for rooted devices and will not work if they detect the device is rooted - the logic is that a rooted device may not have the same protection for the media path and the keys.

If for your use case you don't actually need DRM, which could be the case if the streams you want to play are not encrypted, then it may be worth looking at your application and removing any DRM configuration or libraries it includes.

**Update**

The term DRM can be used generally to describe Digital Rights Management for anything, e.g. software, book, media etc, or to refer to the common DRM solutions used to protect media such as Widevine, PlayReady, FairPlay etc.

Unfortunately, the LG WebOS documentation seems to use the term for both which makes it hard to interpret the type of error you are seeing.

The manual for the error code you are seeing simply suggests the error message should be "Failed to check DRM.'

- http://webostv.developer.lge.com/api/webos-service-api/application-manager/?wos_flag=launch#launch.

This might be a reference to a media DRM, but it also could be talking about the DRM used to sign and protect apps themselves.

LG have a WebOS security solutions guide also that explains their app signing security which you may be able to find on the web.

I suspect that the error message you are seeing is related to this use of the term 'DRM'.

Assuming that is the case, then unfortunatly, you are either going to have to remove this security framework in your device, which I suspect will not be trivial, or submit the app to the LG content store.

Comment: Thanks. The App is a simple Web app, redirecting to a webpage. I am 100% sure there is no encription or DRM options and elements at all. I can manage to install it via SSH, but cant lunch it, or see it in the TV menu. I can only install and lunch it as a temporary app.

Comment: Update added above - I think you will find it hard to work around this unfortunately.